# SQL using the except clause

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

- Table 1 has 4 columns

  - column1 is my id
  - column2 is int
  - column3 is date
  - column4 is varchar
- Table 2 has 5 columns

  - column1 is id
  - column2 is int
  - column3 is int
  - column4 is varchar
  - column5 is varchar.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 >= #today#
EXCEPT
SELECT column3
FROM table2
WHERE column2 = '2628'
ORDER BY table1.column2
```

When I display my results, it displays the information I want, but I would like it to display table1, column3…

Here is my output: (I am using ColdFusion)

```
cfoutput query="date"
School Day - #table1column2# br
/cfoutput

47
48
49
52
53
55
```

I would like it display like this:

```
11/1/2018
11/2/2018
11/3/2018
11/6/2018
11/8/2018
```

I have tried to `INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column2 = table2.column3` but it does not seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please make your question more readable

Comment: MySQL does not support `except` clause

Comment: Please format the code sections like this: `code = code_lol`.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Try to clearly state expected output for some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use an `except` or would a `not exists` work?

If I understand you want all records from table1 
except those matching table2 column3 on table1 column2 where table2's column2 has a value of 2628.

I use 1 in the subquery as the value returned there is not important.  we use correlation to join t1 to t2 and limit t2's column 2 to the desired value.

As the data you're after is in table1 and nothing is needed from table2; I tend to put table 2 in the where clause as it is a filter on the data you want to see from table1.  If you needed data from table2 I'd probably use a left join here.

```
SELECT t1.column2, t1.column3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.column3 >= #today# 
 and not exists (SELECT 1 
                FROM table2 t2
                WHERE  t1.column2 = t2.column3
                  and t2.column2 = '2628')
ORDER BY T1.column2
```

I'm not a big fan of ordering by a column and not displaying it so I left it in the query results.

Except will only work here if you limit to t1.column2 and t2.column3 and then use that as subquery to get the records from t1 you want.  This seems like unneeded overhead given not exists can do it in one step.